# I have trouble with Matrices in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, math, matrix

This code works for multiply 2 matrix which it send matrix a and matrix b and them pointer to matrixMultiply method.

But I have trouble at the line "matrix12[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k];"

```
double **matrixMultiply(double *matrix1,double *matrix2,int row1,int col1,int col2){

    double **matrix12 = malloc(sizeof(double*)*row1);
    for (int i=0; i<row1; i++){
        matrix12[i] = malloc(sizeof(double*)col2);

        for (int j=0; j<col2; j++){
            matrix12[i][j] = 0.0;

            for (int k=0; k<col1; k++){
                matrix12[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k]; //invalid operands to binary expression
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix12;
}

double *kmult = *matrixMultiply(a, b, 4, 4, 4,);
```

Ps.This code declare in ViewController.m

Comment: "Could you fix it right?" - Not entirely right. I don't know what it is supposed to do, what it does currently, and how much you will pay for it.

Comment: What is `b`? I guess `b[k]` should be replaced by `matrix2[k] and `matrix1[i][k]` should be replaced by `matrix1[n]` with `n` being either `i` or `k` or `j` or so. That is hard to say and just guesswork without knowing what you want to achieve. But with `matrix1` being `double*` you shound not access a 2nd dimension.

Comment: What have I change double* to?

Comment: It's pure C, not Objective-C.

Comment: Yes,I know but I can't change C to Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure Matrix1 is a 2-dimension matrix? It's declared at a 1-dimension matrix: double *matrix1 instead of "double **matrix1"
That's probably why the line matrix12[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k]; doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks you.It works.Anyway,in the line "double *kmult = *matrixMultiply(a, b, 4, 4, 4,);"It's incompatible pointer types too.